# How we can externally run NodeJS service which is hosted in PCF?

Tags: node.js, cloud-foundry

We have hosted NodeJS service in Pivotal Cloud Foundry (PCF) and we have to run hosted service as per particular schedule from externally. So looking for your assistance in this regards?

Having said that, when service run is required, we will tell service to run, and suppose again re run require then will again tell service to run.

Answer (score 0):

you need a scheduler like Autosys to trigger your micro-service externally. Autosys latest versions support web call but you can run curl to trigger the MS even if on older version. Please note that some of the scheduler might have 'trigger and forget' so you may need to have your process (MS and script integration) intelligent enough to capture the failure and trigger an event if that's reqd. Few possible options to capture the status of the execution:

1. A little bit of tweaking in your micro-service; like use some DB
   updates or S3 update  at the end (and error/failure) and keep
   checking that status within your script and adjust the status based
   on outcome.
2. Other option is use [Tasks](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/using-tasks.html) within PCF - you can have long
   running task and can use api to get their status regularly via script
   running on scheduler and capture the status.

Basically you need to derive that logic somehow to capture the successful or failure status.

On other side; you may have a scheduler service within PCF itself like using batch spring scheduler or NodeJs lib. which may trigger the job as per the crom schedule but it might not provide more flexibility in terms of adhoc run etc so easily.

Comment: Yes agree, whatever scheduler options you mentioned all are one way only, but we are looking for scheduler, form which which we can trigger job and also in case of failure it should return error status code as well so we can check the run status of job. thanks

Comment: I've updated the details above with few ways of communicating back to scheduler.

Comment: So basically there is no direct way to handle this scenario, but we can follow alternative way like as uses of run-task, and DB updates or S3 update, to manually track it. thanks again